Is it possible to make a single tab in a tabbar not push sliverappbar tabbar up when scrolled?
I'm really new to flutter development so hopefully I can explain my problem correctly.
I have the following screen setup:

It's a Sliverappbar with tabbar/view.   The "General" and "Looks" tabs contain a lot of fields, so I want to be able to scroll those tabs, and am currently able to do so.   The "Stats" tab however (the one shown in the screenshot) perfectly displays everything without require pushing the tab bar up or scrolling though, so I'd like to make it so if that tab is selected then no pushing by the user is allowed.  The Keyboard should still push it up though when it appears, which it currently does, I just want to make it so that when no keyboard is present that you can't drag the "page" up like the First and third tab.  Is there a way to do this?
If it helps, here's the page code:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3, // Adjust the number of tabs accordingly
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                expandedHeight: 320,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                title: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(widget.modelrecord.name,
                        style: DetailTextStyles.detailHeadlineMedium),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 8, 12, 8),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.close_rounded,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 209, 209),
                        size: 24,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                snap: false,
                flexibleSpace: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 40),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(widget.modelrecord
                                    .photo), // Replace with your image
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            _showChangeImageDialog(context);
                          },
                        ),
                        // const SizedBox(height: 16),

                        // // Button beneath the picture
                        // ElevatedButton(
                        //   onPressed: () {
                        //     // Action for button press
                        //   },
                        //   child: const Text('Change Picture'),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    )),

                /// Tabs
                bottom: TTabBar(tabcontroller: _tabController, tabs: [
                  //Tab(text: 'General'),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text("General",
                          style: DetailTextStyles.detailTabLabel)),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text("Stats",
                          style: DetailTextStyles.detailTabLabel)),
                  Tab(
                      child: Text("Looks",
                          style: DetailTextStyles.detailTabLabel)),
                ])),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: [
                        // Replace these containers with your actual form/content
                        ModelsGeneralTab(),
                        const ModelsStatsTab(),
                        _buildLooksTab(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: FilledButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Button action
                      },
                      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 48),
                      ),
                      child: Text('Save',
                          style: DetailTextStyles.detailLabelMedium),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

